# Can you use LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis) as part of sklearn pipeline for preprocessing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

So this is what I put together to run the data through variance threshold for feature selection, then normalizer and LDA for dimensionality reduction.

The LDA element I'm not too sure about as I can't find any examples of this being used in a pipeline (as dimensionality reduction / data transformation technique as opposed to a standalone classifier.)

I am a bit worried, as when this is used and the transformed data passed on to a series  classifiers - they result in a series of identical accuracy, precision, recall and F1 scores. Only the application of AdaBoost brings back something different.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('feature_selection', VarianceThreshold()),
    ('normaliser', Normalizer()),
    ('lda', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis())], verbose = True)


X_train_post_pipeline = pipeline.fit_transform(X_train, Y_train)
X_test_post_pipeline = pipeline.transform(X_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

`LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` is a is a dimensionality reduction technique that can be compared to `PCA`. Therefore it can be used within a pipeline as preprocessing.

It is possible that classifier that used its result end up with the same score as LDA project inputs to the most discriminative directions.

Below is an example of a pipeline that is using LDA as a preprocessing steps:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2)

pipe = make_pipeline(VarianceThreshold(),
                     Normalizer(),
                     LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
                     LogisticRegression())

pipe.fit(X, y)
```